# NFS mount on Windows 11: can't write to NFS share

Tags: linux, mount, windows-11, file-permissions, nfs

I have an NFS v4 server running on an Ubuntu box in my LAN and need to mount one of its shares onto a desktop running Windows 11 Pro (with Services for NFS enabled).

This is what I have on the Ubuntu box (NFS server):

`/etc/exports`:

```
/mnt/files 192.168.0.0/16(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

`/etc/passwd`:

```
rodrix:x:1000:1000:Rodrix:/home/rodrix:/bin/bash
```

`/etc/group`:

```shell
rodrix:x:1000:
mynetwork:x:1002:rodrix
```

Permissions on `/mnt/files/` directory: `drwxrwxr-x  5 root mynetwork`

I can mount the share on my Linux laptop and read + write without a problem (user ID is `1000` and belongs to the `mynetwork` group on that machine as well). On Windows 11 Pro, though, I can mount but can't write to the NFS share. Here's what I have on Windows:

`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\passwd`:

```shell
192.168.1.101\rodrix:x:1000:1000:My NFS user:C:\Users\rodrix
```

`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\group`:

```shell
192.168.1.101\mynetwork:x:1002:1000
```

I must be doing something wrong but can't really tell where: is it on the NFS share itself (Ubuntu box `192.168.1.101`) or is it on the NFS client configs for Windows 11?

Comment: Aside from the problem, my general impression is that Microsoft only cares the _absolute bare minimum_ about their NFS client (even keeping it far behind their own NFS server), and you'd have much better luck serving SMBv3 from Ubuntu instead...

Comment: I got it to work with the `passwd` file, but I have to agree with you about SMB being better suited for Windows clients. In an ideal world, I'd like to do NFS from WSL2, but I've already wasted too much time trying to get that to work without luck. [Topic for another SU question, for sure.]

Answer (score 1):

That is NFSv3 not NFSv4. As far as I can tell, the latter is not supported by Windows 7..11, only Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, the issue was just syntax. There should be no domain name in the `passwd` file on Windows (`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\passwd`). So, instead of this:

```
192.168.1.101\rodrix:x:1000:1000:My NFS user:C:\Users\rodrix
```

It should be just this:

```
rodrix:x:1000:1000:My NFS user:C:\Users\rodrix
```

As for the group file (`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\group`), it seems to be ignored by Windows, but I can live with that.